# Stored procedure without transaction

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that performs calculations and stores a large amount of data in new tables, in another database.
If anything goes wrong, I just drop the tables.

I've already set the recovery mode for this database as simple, as the data is available elsewhere. Is there anything else I can do in the stored procedure to limit writing to the transaction log or remove transactions entirely to speed up the process?

Comment: Is this primarily a performance issue or an issue with the size of the transaction log? Either way how complex is your stored procedure? Can you isolate the issue to a single statement in your stored procedure?

Comment: I'm primarily concerned with performance. It takes about 30 min to run, and can be run many times a day.

Comment: So the transaction log is not necessarily relevant. You'll need to isolate which pieces of your code are slow and post them in order for us to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is impossible to completely eliminate transaction log from the equation in SQL Server.

You may try to check bulk logged recovery model in conjunction with `bulk insert`, but if your calculations are complex and cannot be expressed within a single `select` statement, it could be worth trying SSIS.

Comment: I've set the recovery model to simple, which is similar to Bulk Insert

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you that using SSIS package in order to convert data from one database to another database. in SSIS you can control converted data and can use balk insert. In buck insert mode you limit your database to write transaction logs completely.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into similar situations even while using SSIS where my staging database(s) kept logs more then 10 times the size of the actual data (on simple logging and using bulk insert). After lots of searching I have found that it is not feasable to prevent this from happening when doing large data operations like loading a datawarehouse. Instead it is easier to just clean up after you are done by shrinking the log.

[dbcc shrinkfile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189493.aspx)